# Can i use if statement in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to create a query that will generate their total use of usage that depends on prices. I don't know if this is possible in just query, so here it is.

Main table // This table is for all the people, so this is continuos, this can be added, the ID column is unique.

```
 id          price       date_created
 25           8.5         2019-08-16
 26           11.5        2019-08-01
```

electricity table // This table is continuos base on the main_id, as long as the main_id is existence in the `Main table` every day this `usage` table will have its everyday value for all the main_id that is existing in the main table. this is like the electricity generated for their everyday use.

```
id    main_id           current_usage  date_generated
1         25                10         2019-08-16     
2         25                10         2019-08-17
3         25                10         2019-08-18
4         25                10         2019-08-19
5         25                10         2019-08-20
6         25                10         2019-08-21
7         26                20         2019-08-01
8         26                 5         2019-08-02
9         26                 5         2019-08-03
10        26                10         2019-08-04
```

My query

```
SELECT main.id
     , main.price
     , SUM(electricity.current_usage)*main.price total_generated
     , electricity.date_generated
  FROM main AS main
 INNER JOIN electricity AS electricity
    ON main.id = electricity.main_id
 GROUP 
    BY MONTH(electricity.date_generated);
```

Here I don't have a problem Because what I want to get here is just One is to One.

so the output will be

```
id             price        total_genereated
25              8.5              510
26              11.5             460
```

here is what my problem is, This is where I got stuck

there is a table of `price_history` , this table has the purpose of, that the price can change anytime for that main_id in the `Main table`.

```
id  main_id    changed_price            price_date_changed
1      25             15                    2019-08-18
2      26             20                    2019-08-03
```

instead of getting just two rows only. I need to have 4 rows here because of the price history. the price has changed.

Sample output

```
id             price        total_genereated          date_range
25              8.5              170            2019-08-16 - 2019-08-17
25              15               600            2019-08-18 - 2019-08-21 
26              11.5             287            2019-08-01 - 2019-08-02
26              20               300            2019-08-03 - 2019-08-04
```

I don't know if my idea is really possible just by Only doing it on Query, i am really stuck with this problem. What I am thinking is to use IF statement here in MYSQL or this is just way to complicated to do in Query?

Comment: You can use JOIN between your result and the table price_history

Comment: The purpose of your database structure is not clear. You have not explained anything about what you're trying to store here. For instance: Are prices known at the time of usage? Your chosen database structure suggests that this might not the case. However, if it always is, you could simplify the structure by getting rid of the 'main' table.

Comment: Is main_id in  price_history table a unique field?

Comment: @Mohammed Shafeek. Its the foreign key for the main_table. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: foreign key ok..but is it unique or repeated one?

Comment: @Mohammed Shafeek It can be repeated. For each main_id. The price can always be change. Its like the billing for electricity.

Comment: @JanessaBautista can you show an expected result for that repeated scenario?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek hi, i edited my post, and explain each table. sorry if i didn't explain them so well. thanks!

Comment: @JanessaBautista my question is different..price_history  table has one more entry for main_id 25...then show an expected output for you..

Comment: @MohammedShafeek the ```main_id``` in the ```main table``` has its own original price of 8.5 for the date of ```2019-08-16``` but the price change from ```2019-08-18``` so there will be two output of rows. one is from the price of ```8.5``` from the range date of ```2019-08-16 - 2019-08-17``` only   and  the second is for the price of ```15``` from the range date of ```2019-08-18 - 2019-08-21 ```. the total_generated will depend on the date of price history and the original price.

Comment: @JanessaBautista Note that `usage` is a [Reserved Keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U) . Please consider naming the table something else instead.

Comment: @JanessaBautista Also, what is your MySQL server version ? Run `SELECT Version();` and report the result of this query please.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Hi, i already change it sorry for the misunderstanding. here is the version 10.1.34-MariaDB

Comment: @JanessaBautista will it be possible for you to upgrade to latest version of MariaDB ? Or, atleast 10.2+. Your problem is complex and it will become little simpler to solve it using Window/Analytic functions.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya im afraid i cant change it :(

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e653ca/2)**

First you need to put all the prices together:

```
SELECT id as main_id, price, date_created
FROM main

UNION

SELECT main_id, changed_price, price_date_changed
FROM price_history
ORDER BY main_id, date_created;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| main_id | price | date_created |
|---------|-------|--------------|
|      25 |     9 |   2019-08-16 |
|      25 |    15 |   2019-08-18 |
|      26 |    12 |   2019-08-01 |
|      26 |    20 |   2019-08-03 |
```

Now using a correlated subquery you find the latest price:

```
SELECT id, main_id, current_usage, date_generated,
       ( SELECT price
         FROM ( SELECT id as main_id, price, date_created
                FROM main
                UNION
                SELECT main_id, changed_price, price_date_changed
                FROM price_history
              ) prices
         WHERE prices.main_id = electricity.main_id
           AND prices.date_created <= electricity.date_generated
         ORDER BY prices.date_created DESC
         LIMIT 1 ) as price
FROM electricity
ORDER BY main_id, date_generated;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | main_id | current_usage | date_generated | price |
|----|---------|---------------|----------------|-------|
|  1 |      25 |            10 |     2019-08-16 |     9 |
|  2 |      25 |            10 |     2019-08-17 |     9 |
|  3 |      25 |            10 |     2019-08-18 |    15 |
|  4 |      25 |            10 |     2019-08-19 |    15 |
|  5 |      25 |            10 |     2019-08-20 |    15 |
|  6 |      25 |            10 |     2019-08-21 |    15 |
|  7 |      26 |            20 |     2019-08-01 |    12 |
|  8 |      26 |             5 |     2019-08-02 |    12 |
|  9 |      26 |             5 |     2019-08-03 |    20 |
| 10 |      26 |            10 |     2019-08-04 |    20 |
```

Comment: +1; I was on the similar lines; was just trying to replicate the format OP wants. But this should work and rest OP should be able to handle in the application code.