# SELECT then UPDATE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

i am selecting the first highest timestamp in my data, and i want to update the second highest timestamp based on the date of my highest timestamp. it looks like this.

Dated table

```
id        date_created            date_updated
1       2019-10-01 1:00:00        0000-00-00 0:00:00
2       2019-10-01 2:00:00        0000-00-00 0:00:00
```

i can already select the second highest date which is the `2019-10-01 1:00:00`

HERE is my query for selecting it.

```
SELECT MAX(date_created),date_updated
  FROM dated
  WHERE date_created < (SELECT MAX(date_created)
  FROM dated)
```

my problem is, how can i update the `date_updated` column data that i selected from my query, to have the value of the highest date which is the `2019-10-01 2:00:00`

Comment: If you are trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58162966/2469308), it won't be *efficient* without using MySQL 8+/MariaDB 10.2+ (Window/Analytic functions)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya You can still be efficient without install a new db version.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I cant argue with that; but give it a try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58162966/2469308) :-)

Comment: I dont see any anwer there, and OP already said cant upgrade

Comment: 2nd highest in a data set of 'two', is hardly representative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04733/1)**

```
 UPDATE dated
 SET date_updated = (SELECT MAX(date_created) 
                     FROM (SELECT date_created
                           FROM dated) as t
                    )
 WHERE date_created = ( SELECT MAX(date_created)
                        FROM (SELECT date_created
                              FROM dated) as t
                        WHERE date_created < (SELECT MAX(date_created) 
                                              FROM (SELECT date_created
                                                    FROM dated) as t)
                      )
```

Comment: hi, that's what i did earlier but i am getting this error of ```Table 'dated' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
UPDATE DATED
SET DATE_CREATED = (SELECT MAX(DATE_CREATED) FROM DATED)
WHERE DATE_CREATED = (SELECT MIN(DATE_CREATED) FROM DATED)
```

(not tested)

Comment: You cant use the same table you are trying to update on the subquery. check my ansswer

Comment: Yes sorry about that. Just create a virtual table to get the max date and keep the rest as it is